# Sub the string value of every other row in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Say I have a basic dataframe like the following:

```
X1 X2 X3
1  4  aeven
2  4  beven
3  1  ceven
4  2  deven
5  3  geven
```

Suppose I want to `sub()` the value of every other row in column X3, replacing "odd" with "even". How can I do this only or every other row?

The desired output would be the following:

```
X1 X2 X3
1  4  aodd
2  4  beven
3  1  codd
4  2  deven
5  3  godd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dt)[seq(1,.N,2), X3:=sub("even", "odd", X3)]
```

Output:

```
      X1    X2     X3
   <int> <int> <char>
1:     1     4   aodd
2:     2     4  beven
3:     3     1   codd
4:     4     2  deven
5:     5     3   godd
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `%%` to check the remainder of `row_number` (or use column `X1` if it represents the row index) after dividing by 2, then use an `ifelse` to catch that and do `sub`.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(X3 = ifelse(as.logical(row_number() %% 2), sub("even", "odd", X3), X3))

  X1 X2    X3
1  1  4  aodd
2  2  4 beven
3  3  1  codd
4  4  2 deven
5  5  3  godd
```

Answer (score 1):

A `base` option

```r
i <- seq(1, nrow(x), by = 2)
x$X3[i] <- sub("even", "odd", x$X3[i])

#------
  X1 X2    X3
1  1  4  aodd
2  2  4 beven
3  3  1  codd
4  4  2 deven
5  5  3  godd
```

---

Data

```
x <- structure(list(X1 = 1:5, X2 = c(4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L), 
                    X3 = c("aeven", "beven", "ceven", "deven", "geven")), 
               class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```